# What is the AVG Search Bar?

Tags: avg-antivirus

Lately I was surprised to see AVG Search take over my home page which used to be the default Google search page.

I managed to remove this strange thing, but I am not sure how it got in with all of the security protection on the machine?
How would you classify such a program (virus, etc.?) and how would any company allow to do this without permissions?

Also, if it managed to get in maybe it is still in listening and copying information without the user knowing. How to make absolutely sure it is gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVG search toolbar comes along with some third party software installation. They ask you to set it default search and accept the term and conditions, but you can unmark the option. You have accidently didn't read through out the installation process of the third party software.

After removing it you can check it out in the `Program and Feature` section from where we can uninstall the applications, you can check it out under the plugin option of your default browser if its not there then its not on your machine any more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I installed WinZip trial lately and a Java upgrade. I guess it is not the Java upgrade.

Comment: Most probably its the Winzip trial which installed it on your machine, and I don't think that Java need these kind of junk.